# if statement fall through output issues

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, case

whenever I enter a different case and enter an hour that meets the if statements requirements the else also gets printed, help I just need one output from each different situation. 
the example below is the error I get.
ex: enter 'a' enter '11' output 'the amount due is 11.95' 'the amount due is 9.95'

```
//Libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//Global Constants

//Functioning Prototypes

//Execution Begins here
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
//Declare Variables
char pack;
int hours;
float due;

//prompt user
cout<<"Please choose one monthly internet subscription package: a, b, or c\n";
cin>>pack;
cout<<"Enter how many hours were that month used\n";
cin>>hours;

//process 
cout<<setprecision(2)<<fixed<<showpoint;
switch (pack){

    case 'a':
        if (hours>=10 && hours<=744){
            hours=(hours-10)*2;
            due=hours;
            due+=9.95;
            cout<<"The amount due is $"<<due<<endl;
        }
        else if (hours>=744){
                cout<<"ERROR: a month cannot exceed 744 hours\n";
        }
        else ( hours<=10);{
            due=9.95;
            cout<<"The amount due is $"<<due<<endl;
        }
        break;
    case 'b':
        if (hours>20 && hours<744){
            hours=(hours-20);
            due=hours;
            due+=14.95;
            cout<<"The amount due is $"<<due<<endl;
        }
        else if (hours>=744){
            cout<<"ERROR: a month cannot exceed 744 hours\n";
        }
        else (hours<=20);{
            due=14.95;
            cout<<"The amount due is $"<<due<<endl;
        }
        break;
    case 'c':

        if (hours>=744){
            cout<<"ERROR: a month cannot exceed 744 hours\n";
        }
        else if (hours<744);{
            due=19.95;
            cout<<"The amount due is $"<<due<<endl;

        }
        break;
    }
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You have semicolons after some of your `else` and `else if` parameters.

Comment: Oh, There is a spy among ';'s!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
else (hours<=20);{
        due=14.95;
        cout<<"The amount due is $"<<due<<endl;
    }
```

is equivalent to:

```
else (hours<=20) {
//Do nothing
}

{
    due=14.95;
    cout<<"The amount due is $"<<due<<endl;
}
```

You need to remove the ";". Otherwise, the last code block will always be executed because it isn't part of the else block.

Comment: I removed them but I'm having the same issues with the output falling through

Comment: "You need to remove the ";"." - true, but also to put an `if` after the `else` (or, given this condition should always be true, you can remove the `(hours <= 20)` and just have `} else { ...`).  `else if (hours<744);{` only has the extra semicolon, i.e. should be `else if (hours<744) {`.

Comment: also when I removed the semicolons I get an error expected ; before ( on the else lines. even after I put a semicolon after the } in the else block.

Comment: thank you tony d I finally got it work! and thanks everyone for their input!